# Implementing Radix sort in java - quite a few questions

Tags: arrays, sorting, recursion

Although it is not clearly stated in my excercise, I am supposed to implement [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) recursively. I've been working on the task for days, but yet, I only managed to produce garbage, unfortunately. We are required to work with two methods. The sort method receives a certain array with numbers ranging from 0 to 999 and the digit we are looking at. We are supposed to generate a two-dimensional matrix here in order to distribute the numbers inside the array. So, for example, 523 is positioned at the fifth row and 27 is positioned at the 0th row since it is interpreted as 027.

I tried to do this with the help of a switch-case-construct, dividing the numbers inside the array by 100, checking for the remainder and then position the number with respect to the remainder. Then, I somehow tried to build buckets that include only the numbers with the same digit, so for example, 237 and 247 would be thrown in the same bucket in the first "round". I tried to do this by taking the whole row of the "fields"-matrix where we put in the values before.

In the putInBucket-method, I am required to extent the bucket (which I managed to do right, I guess) and then returning it.

I am sorry, I know that the code is total garbage, but maybe there's someone out there who understands what I am up to and can help me a little bit.

I simply don't see how I need to work with the buckets here, I even don't understand why I have to extent them, and I don't see any way to returning it back to the sort-method (which, I think, I am required to do).

**Further description:**

The whole thing is meant to work as follows: We take an array with integers ranging from 0 to 999. Every number is then sorted by its first digit, as mentioned above. Imagine you have buckets denoted with the numbers ranging from 0 to 9. You start the sorting by putting 523 in bucket 5, 672 in bucket 6 and so on. This is easy when there is only one number (or no number at all) in one of the buckets. But it gets harder (and that's where recursion might come in hand) when you want to put more than one number in one bucket. The mechanism now goes as follows: We put two numbers with the same first digit in one bucket, for example 237 and 245. Now, we want to sort these numbers again by the same algorithm, meaning we call the sort-method (somehow) again with an array that only contains these two numbers and sorting them again, but now my we do by looking at the second digit, so we would compare 3 and 4. We sort every number inside the array like this, and at the end, in order to get a sorted array, we start at the end, meaning at bucket 9, and then just put everything together. If we would be at bucket 2, the algorithm would look into the recursive step and already receive the sorted array [237, 245] and deliver it in order to complete the whole thing.

**My own problems:**

I don't understand why we need to extent a bucket and I can't figure it out from the description. It is simply stated that we are supposed to do so. I'd imagine that we would to it to copy another element inside it, because if we have the buckets from 0 to 9, putting in two numbers inside the same bucket would just mean that we would overwrite the first value. This might be the reason why we need to return the new, extended bucket, but I am not sure about that. Plus, I don't know how to go further from there. Even if I have an extened bucket now, it's not like I can simply stick it to the old matrix and copy another element into it again.

```
public static int[] sort(int[] array, int digit) {

  if (array.length == 0)
    return array;

  int[][] fields = new int[10][array.length];
  int[] bucket = new int[array.length];
  int i = 0;

  for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    switch (array[j] / 100) {

    case 0: i = 0; break;
    case 1: i = 1; break;

    ...

    }

   fields[i][j] = array[j]
   bucket[i] = fields[i][j];
  }
  return bucket;
  }

private static int[] putInBucket(int [] bucket, int number) {

  int[] bucket_new = int[bucket.length+1];

  for (int i = 1; i < bucket_new.length; i++) {
    bucket_new[i] = bucket[i-1];
  }
  return bucket_new;
  }

public static void main (String [] argv) {

  int[] array = readInts("Please type in the numbers: ");
  int digit = 0;
  int[] bucket = sort(array, digit);
  }
```

Comment: Would you please fix your indentation and supply a call or two to illustrate the problems?

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: (1) Your indentation is inconsistent.  (2) Your posted code is supposed to reproduce the problem as given -- but you have no main program.  Did you take the intro tour when you signed up?

Comment: I cut the main program out since, up to this point, it only calls the sort-method. What is wrong with my indentation though? That's the way they taught us.

Comment: A refresh helped the code display (perhaps my browser was at fault).  You still appear to have a couple of lines indented 3 spaces, instead of 2 or 4.  That's a secondary issue.  The main one is lack of the expected code and problem description.  See [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for starters.

Comment: Okay, I'll put in the main method then.

Comment: Did it as you wished.

Comment: And I gave a further description. I don't know how to explain it any better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't use digit in sort, that's quite suspicious
- The switch/case looks like a quite convoluted way to write `i = array[j] / 100`
- I'd recommend to read the wikipedia description of radix sort.
- The expression to extract a digit from a base 10 number is `(number / Math.pow(10, digit)) % 10`.
- Note that you can count digits from left to right or right to left, make sure you get this right.
- I suppose you first want to sort for digit 0, then for digit 1, then for digit 2. So there should be a recursive call at the end of sort that does this.
- Your buckets array needs to be 2-dimensional. You'll need to call it this way: `buckets[i] = putInBucket(buckets[i], array[j])`. If you handle null in putInBuckets, you don't need to initialize it.
- The reason why you need a 2d bucket array and putInBucket (instead of your fixed size field) is that you don't know how many numbers will end up in each bucket
- The second phase (reading back from the buckets to the array) is missing before the recursive call
- make sure to stop the recursion after 3 digits

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I guess my biggest mistake here was to assume that I need to work with a swtich-case-construct, which is far more complicated. Your description makes much more sense, thank you!